# How is it possible for 4 distinguishable particles that the particle with the largest mass occupies the first excited state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, identical-particles

In the system of 4 distinguishable particles. How is it possible that the more massive particle went into the first excited states while the rest of the particles remained in their ground states?DO the particle with more mass have higher energy which causes its transition from one state to another? As it is written in the last paragraph of the image file. [! [Enter image description here] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIAId.png)] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIAId.png)

Comment: Generally, the greater the mass discrepancy/energy discrepancy, more probable is the decay of a particle/the emission of energy. It makes sense if you notice nature always try to minimize the energy of a system.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the energies go as 1/mass, the particle with the largest mass has the lowest eigenenergies. That is, it's second excited state is smaller than the excited states of the other particles. Thus, to get the second smallest energy, put that one particle in its excited state and all the others in their ground states.